# NSOpenGLContext for non-drawing purposes

Tags: cocoa, opengl, openglcontext, nsopengl

How to create a system-independent `NSOpenGLContext` in Cocoa, not for drawing, but for retrieving OpenGL information like vendor, version etc. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create one the same way you would "for drawing," but after creating it, you get the information you want and then destroy it.